# How to receive website url from other apps, such as Google

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, browser

I'm a new developer. Can someone help me on how to receive website URLs from other apps? My app is currently my default browser, but my problem is that, I don't know how to receive the website URL.

[Here's the preview of the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EscL.png)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                if (sharedText != null) {
                    // Update UI to reflect text being shared
                    webview1.loadUrl(action);
                }
            }
        }
```

I try to use the code above but it doesn't work.

Also, I don't know how to detect when a user clicks the 'done' or 'go' button in the edittext on the status bar above (see the pic).

I tried this code, but my app keeps closing:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
           //do what you want on the press of 'done'
           submit.performClick();
        }    
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please help me.

Edit:
I already added an intent filter:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ReceiveUrlActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http"/> 

            <data android:scheme="https"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: Have you added the intent filter to your activity?

Comment: Yes. I already added an intent filter.

Comment: You have to remove the autoVerify tag.

Comment: I try, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think this code is wrong or not working: Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                if (sharedText != null) {
                    // Update UI to reflect text being shared
                    webview1.loadUrl(action);
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**
Add access to the Internet

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
...
<application
....
```

At the activity that will open when sharing add

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

**MyActivity.java**
First, make sure that there is a share to your application

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, type+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) handleSendText(intent);
        
    }
    ...
}
```

Process the data after confirming it and show it

```
    private void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText == null) return;
    WebView webview1 = findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview1.loadUrl(sharedText);
}
```

---

[for more information](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)